# Power transformer dual secondaries connection

Tags: transformer

I am new to electronics and want to build simple circuit.

I bought Radio Shack Power Transformer which converts from 120 V to 12 V or 6 V, it says on the back that if I connect two yellow wires it will be 12 V and if I use black and yellow it will be 6 V. My question is, can I use both at  the same time to power up two devices one 6 V and one 12 V?

Thanks

Comment: Part number or datasheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPvLPL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Multiple transformer configurations.*

If there are four secondary wires then you have two independent 6 V secondaries. This is quite flexible and you can configure them in a variety of ways as shown in Figure 1.

- **0 - 6, 0 - 6** gives you two independent 6 V windings.
- **0 - 6, parallel** gives you one 6 V output but with double the current.
- **6 - 0 - 6** gives a 'centre-tapped' output. This is used in some dual rail power supplies. Normally the centre-tap would be grounded.
- **0 - 6 - 12** is the same but the bottom terminal would be grounded.

You want the 0 - 6 - 12 arrangement. Because the current from both your circuits will return on the bottom winding it must be able to handle the sum of the currents. Post details in your question if you have further questions.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI7Xzi.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Wiring 6 V and 12 V loads.*

Answer (score 0):

As long as your devices don't use more combined amperage than the transformer's rating & you make sure to keep your circuits independant, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the dot conventions. You can find out your transformer's dot conventions from its data sheet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCo3w3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the voltage values on the circuit has no \$+\$ or \$-\$ signs since we are talking about AC voltage.